# class_addMethod on iphone (objective-c)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm trying to use the answer accepted here: [Dynamic UIMenuItems with @selector and dynamic methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249182/)
But it gives a warning (and it doesn't work) of: implicit declaration of function 'class_addMethod'

I have searched google but have no idea?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add `#include <objc/runtime.h>` to the top of your implementation file (.m or .c).

Comment: Even better is `#include <objc/objc-runtime.h>`

Comment: it is under `/usr/include/objc/objc-runtime.h` so is `runtime.h`