# UIMenuController custom item on UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

I have an `UIMenuController` I add a custom button and all works fine, it shows it and my defined selector gets called but my problem is, I only get the UIMenuController itself as the parameter but how can I know on which IndexPath the action was called?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861249/uimenucontroller-how-to-tell-which-menuitem-is-pressed

Comment: I dont see how it can help me in this situation

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16270198/308315